# Execute a command after some time if no input from user

Tags: bash, shell-script

**See [this answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642396/224511) for a zsh solution**

---

Let's say I have the following in my `~/.bash_aliases` to ask for confirmation before suspending the system:

```
function suspend()
{ #
    echo "Please confirm/cancel system suspension:"
    select confirmation in "confirm" "cancel"; do
        case ${confirmation} in
        confirm )
            echo "System suspending..."
            systemctl suspend
            break;;
        cancel )
            echo "Canceled suspension."
            break;;
        esac
    done
}
```

I would like `systemctl suspend` to be still executed if no answer is given by the user. For example, after 10 seconds without user input, the content of the "confirm" case would be executed.

I tried the following, with a backgrounded `sleep` in a subshell:

```
function suspend()
{ #
    flag_cancel=0
    echo "Please confirm/cancel system suspension:"
    (
    sleep 10 &&
        if [ $flag_cancel -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "System suspending..."
        systemctl suspend
        fi &
    )
    select confirmation in "confirm" "cancel"; do
    case ${confirmation} in
        confirm )
        echo "System suspending..."
        systemctl suspend
        break;;
        cancel )
        flag_cancel=1
        echo "Canceled suspension."
        break;;
    esac
    done
}
```

but a change of the value of `flag_cancel` is not taken into account, so the command is always executed after the `sleep`.

How to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt with `sleep` would not work as the `sleep` call and the subsequent test on `$flag_cancel` happens in a background job.  Any change to the variable `flag_cancel` in the main part of the code would not affect the value of the variable in the backgrounded subshell and the code would unconditionally suspend the system after 10 seconds.

Instead, you can use the fact that both `read` and `select` times out after `$TMOUT` seconds in `bash`.

Here's a variation on the theme of your first piece of code:

```bsh
suspend_maybe ()
{
        local PS3='Please confirm/cancel system suspension: '
        local TMOUT=10

        local do_suspend=true

        select confirmation in confirm cancel; do
                case $REPLY in
                        1)
                                # default case
                                break ;;
                        2)
                                do_suspend=false
                                break ;;
                        *)
                                echo 'Sorry, try again' >&2
                esac
        done

        if "$do_suspend"; then
                echo 'Suspending...'
                systemctl suspend
        else
                echo 'Will not suspend'
        fi
}
```

Changes made:

1. The function is now called `suspend_maybe` since there is already a built-in `suspend` utility in `bash`.
2. The `select` loop uses `PS3` for its prompt.
3. The `select` loop times out after `$TMOUT` seconds.
4. We use the digits in the `case` statement.  That way we don't have to type all the strings in twice.  The value of `$REPLY` will be whatever the user types in.
5. We only need the `select` loop to tell us whether the user wants to *cancel* the suspension of the system.  We treat suspension as the default action.
6. Once we're out of the `select` loop, we suspend the system unless the user chose to cancel that action.

---

The same thing but with an input loop using `read` as a drop-in replacement for `select`:

```bsh
suspend_maybe ()
{
        local PS3='Confirm system suspension [y]/n: '
        local TMOUT=10

        local do_suspend=true

        while true; do
                if ! read -p "$PS3"; then
                        # timeout
                        break
                fi

                case $REPLY in
                        [yY]*)
                                # default case
                                break ;;
                        [nN]*)
                                do_suspend=false
                                break ;;
                        *)
                                echo 'Sorry, try again' >&2
                esac
        done

        if "$do_suspend"; then
                echo 'Suspending...'
                systemctl suspend
        else
                echo 'Will not suspend'
        fi
}
```

Here, the user may enter any string starting with `n` or `N` to cancel the suspension. Letting the `read` time out, entering a word starting with `y` or `Y`,  or pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, would suspend the system.

With the loop above, it is easier to catch the timeout case, in case you want to do anything special when the suspension is happening due to a user not responding to the prompt.  The `break` in the `if`-statement would be triggered whenever the `read` call fails, which it does upon timing out (or when the input stream is closed).

Comment: Is there a way to show the countdown?

Comment: @bilogic Not in an easy way in a comment like this. There's no countdown but a timeout. Converting the code to do a countdown would involve changing it to do a timeout every second for a number of seconds, showing the remaining number of seconds after each interval.

Answer (score 8):

Try with `read` command to get runtime the input from the user. Since it has timeout option.

From man:

> -t timeout
> Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input is not read within timeout seconds.  timeout may be a decimal number with a fractional portion following  the  decimal  point.   This  option  is  only  effective  if  read is reading input from a terminal, pipe, or other special file; it has no effect when reading from regular files.  If timeout is 0, read returns success if input is available on the specified file descriptor, failure otherwise.  The exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded.

Answer (score 3):

In general, an alternative you have is `timeout` from [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html). Not the best choice here, because we are setting a timeout for a builtin command and an external utility can only do it by spawning a whole shell:

```sh
if ! timeout 10 bash -c '
  select conf in yes no
  do
    case $conf in
      (yes) exit 1;;
      (no) exit 0;;
    esac
  done'
then
  echo 'Suspending'
fi
```

Likely more interesting if you are going to ask for input from the user through some external tool, possibly graphical (several of them implement their own timeout mechanism, though).

Note that `timeout` needs the `--foreground` option when not invoked directly from a shell prompt (for instance, if you invoke it in subshell: `( timeout ... )`) and it needs to read from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `t` option of the `read` command.

**For example;**

```
read -t 5 -p "Input within 5 seconds:" data
if [[ $data ]]
then
        echo " Your input is $data"
else
        echo " You didn't any input"
fi
```

**Run script;**

If no give any input within 5 seconds;

```
#~ bash scr.sh 
Input within 5 seconds: You didn't any input
```

If give input in 5 seconds;

```
#~ bash scr.sh
Input within 5 seconds:new data
 Your input is new data
```

Comment: I do something like ``read -t 5 -p "Press Enter to cancel execution ... " || run-my-command``

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with `at`. The advantage: If you have to learn a new tool, learn the most versatile one. `at` schedules commands at arbitrary times in the future. Scheduled jobs can be remove from the queue with `atrm`.

In your case:

```
function suspend()
{ #
    JOBNO=$(echo "systemctl suspend" | at now + 0.2 seconds 2>&1 > /dev/null | awk '{print $2}')
    echo "Please confirm/cancel system suspension:"
    select confirmation in "confirm" "cancel"; do
    case ${confirmation} in
        confirm )
            echo "System suspending..."
            systemctl suspend
            break;;
        cancel )
            echo "Canceled suspension."
        break;;
    esac
    atrm $JOBNO
    done
}
```

Comment: Most `at` implementations have a granularity of 1 minute. I couldn't run `at now + 0.2 seconds`, nor `at now + 60 seconds`, but `at now + 1 minute` works. Does your own `at` command work as in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

#### A solution for zsh

If you are running zsh, then using the `TMOUT` parameter as in [Kusalananda♦'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/610832/224511) will cause zsh to terminate after `$TMOUT` seconds (exiting the shell). To avoid that, the method with `read` can be slightly modified to use the `-t` (timeout) option of `read` and replacing the `-p` option (in zsh, it is not a prompt, see `man zshbuiltins`):

```bsh
suspend_maybe ()
{
    local PS3='Confirm system suspension [y]/n: '
    # local TMOUT=20
    local timeleft=2

        local do_suspend=true

        while true; do
                if ! read -p "$PS3"; then
                        # timeout
                        break
                fi

                case $REPLY in
                        [yY]*)
                                # default case
                                break ;;
                        [nN]*)
                                do_suspend=false
                                break ;;
                        *)
                                echo 'Sorry, try again' >&2
                esac
        done

        if "$do_suspend"; then
                echo 'Suspending...'
                systemctl suspend
        else
                echo 'Will not suspend'
        fi
}
```